# Nextjs No matching service worker detected

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm new to PWA. I tried nextjs pwa tutorial, in Chrome Lighthouse I have this error "Site cannot be installed: No matching service worker detected...". I found similar problems but couldn't find the solution for Nextjs.

P.S. There isn't server.js(for custom routing, use express framework and so on..) file in my Nextjs project.

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
    [
        [
            withPWA,
            {
                pwa: {
                    dest: "public",
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
    nextConfig
);
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "theme_color": "#f69435",
    "background_color": "#f69435",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/",
    "start_url": "/",
    "name": "\ubc25\uc2a4\ud53c",
    "description": "\ubc25\uc2a4\ud53c - \ub864 \uc810\uc218\uc640 \ube44\ub840\ud558\ub294 \ucc2c\ubc25\ucf54\uc778",
    "short_name": "\ubc25\uc2a4\ud53c",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "public/images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "public/images/icons/icon-256x256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "public/images/icons/icon-384x384.png",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "public/images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

_document.tsx

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"
import React from "react"


export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#317EFB" />
        <meta name="description" content="Description" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords" />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icons/icon-192x192.png" />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/iphone5_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/iphone6_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/iphoneplus_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 621px) and (device-height: 1104px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/iphonex_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/iphonexr_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/iphonexsmax_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/ipad_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/ipadpro1_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/ipadpro3_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1194px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
        <link
          href="splashscreens/ipadpro2_splash.png"
          media="(device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
          rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of `next-pwa` (`5.5.5`) it has a bug that breaks the plugin.

https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/issues/378

Downgrade to v5.5.4

Comment: It seems to be without https. I tried in localhost for test. Finally I solved this problem and thanks for answer.